# ElasticSearch NEST return specific fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to write a query that will give me back only one of the fields. Right now I'm storing the filePath of a file and the contents of a file and in my search I want to search against the contents, but only return the filePath.

I'm starting with this statement:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<File>(
        s => s.Query(q => q.Wildcard(w => w.Value("*" + genre + "*").OnField("fileContents"))).AllIndices().AllTypes());
```

Which returns results in `searchResults.Documents` and adding .Fields to it:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<File>(
        s => s.Query(q => q.Wildcard(w => w.Value("*" + genre + "*").OnField("fileContents"))).AllIndices().AllTypes().Fields(f=>f.filePath));
```

And it doesn't have anything in `searchResults.Documents` but it shows the number of hits correctly using `searchResults.Hits.Total`.

The File class is just:

```
public class File
{
  public string filePath { get; set; }
  public string fileContents { get; set; }
}
```

This generates the following json request:

```
{
"fields": [
"filePath"
],
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
     "fileContents": {
        "value": "*int*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which when ran in Sense returns results and when doing `searchResults.Hits.Total` gives the number of hits.

However, there is no records in the `searchResults.Document` IEnumerable.

Is there a different way I'm supposed to be returning the one specific field?

Comment: i found the solution. Here you can see it in another post.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817133/2399279

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the "source" field to specify which fields you want to pull back.  Here is sample code from my application that only returns some fields.

```
        var searchResults = ElasticClient.Search<AuthForReporting>(s => s
            .Size(gridSortData.PageSize)
            .From(gridSortData.PageIndex * gridSortData.PageSize)
            .Sort(sort)
            .Source(sr => sr
                .Include(fi => fi
                    .Add(f => f.AuthEventID)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.AuthEventDate)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthInput.UID)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.CodeID)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.AuthenticationSuccessful)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthInput.UserName)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.ProductID)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.ProductName)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthInput.AuthType)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.Address.City)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.Address.State)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.Address.CountryCode)
                    .Add(f => f.AuthResult.RulesFailed)
                )
            )
            .Query(query)
        );
```

You then access the fields through the "source" in the result:

```
            var finalResult = from x in searchResults.Hits
                   select new AlertListRow
                          {
                              AlertCode = x.Source.AlertCode,
                              AlertDate = x.Source.AlertDate,
                              AlertID = x.Id,
                              AlertSummary = x.Source.Subject,
                              AlertMessage = x.Source.Body
                          };
```

Comment: I was able to do it without having to access the fields through source.